# How to alter progressbar value in Tkinter Python with timer

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, progress-bar

So I am trying to run this code:

```
class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        i = 0
        def timeout():
            global i
            barraProgreso["value"] = i
            i += 1
            print("oli")



        # duration is in seconds

        display = tkinter.Label(self, text="Progreso")
        display.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tkinter.N)
        barraProgreso = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', length=350, mode='determinate')
        barraProgreso.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tkinter.N)

        controller.after(10, timeout())
        #t = Timer(2.0, timeout)
        #t.start()
```

But this error appears:

> local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

I can't get it working and I don't know why, maybe there is some concept about classes and everything they have inside that I am not coding ok, I've been struggling with them for a while as I am kind of new at Python. My goal is to control the value of the progress bar via this timer method.

If you see that I am doing isn't the best way I am opened to all kind of suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `global i` does not refer to the class but the global namespace outside of the class. You should use a class attribute instead.

Comment: `controller.after(10, timeout())` _immediately_ calls `timeout()`. The use of `after` here is pointless. That's likely not the only problem, but it's definitely part of the problem.

Comment: I found out that I shouldn't be calling a timer if not in the main loop, so now I am starting to rewrite the timer related code, get back to you when I have more news!, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want to define `i` as global in your `timeout` method; the `i` defined in `__init__` is not global. It lives within the scope of the `__init__` method.

A better approach is to define `i` as an attribute of your class: `self.i`. Then any method within you class can easily access `self.i`.